# docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: invalid mount {Destination::/app Type:bind on windows 10

Tags: docker

I've spent a long time trying to solve this problem. I search here on StackOverflow, in another place, groups, etc, but without success.

I am trying to build an image python:3.6 on windows but a lot of different errors were returned.

I have a run.py file that runs a python server.

```
import logging
import http.server
import socketserver
import getpass


class MyHTTPHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def log_message(self, format, *args):
        logging.info("%s - - [%s] %s\n"% (
            self.client_address[0], 
            self.log_date_time_string(),
            format%args
        ))

logging.basicConfig(
    filename='/log/http-server.log',
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO
)

logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
logging.info('inicializando...')
PORT = 8000

httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), MyHTTPHandler)
logging.info('escutando a porta: %s', PORT)
logging.info('usuario: %s', getpass.getuser())
httpd.serve_forever()
```

I have a Dockerfile to build my image

```
FROM python:3.6
LABEL maintainer 'Eric Gomes'

RUN useradd www && \
    mkdir /app && \
    mkdir /log && \
    chown www /log

USER www
VOLUME /log
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/python"]
CMD ["run.py"]
```

my actual directory where I am running my docker commands is: **D:\Projetos Dev\treinamento_docker\exercicio\build-dev**

When I run my command:

```
docker container run -it -v ${%D:\Projetos Dev\treinamento_docker\exercicio\build-dev%}:/app -p 80:8000 --name python-server ex-build-dev
```

or

```
docker container run -it -v ${%cd}:/app -p 80:8000 --name python-server ex-build-dev
```

The error is returned:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: invalid mount {Destination::/app Type:bind Source:/var/lib/docker/volumes/227936e587f913e7104daba1b77090fe45290e466bb3dcc1f3a6a6f4d9250e9f/_data Options:[rbind]}: mount destination :/app not absolute: unknown.
```

I tried running on PowerShell and CMD but the result is the same.
Someone may help me, please!?

Comment: If you delete that entire `-v` option, you will run the code that's `COPY`ed into the image.  (Right now it looks like the image is broken since the `run.py` file isn't included in it.)  That would get around this syntax issue, and be a more typical (production-oriented) Docker setup.

Comment: I tried to remove -v, but, if I remove only "-v" a new error happens (docker: invalid reference format.), so if I remove (-v docker: invalid reference format.) a new error is shown: "/usr/local/bin/python: can't open file 'run.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory", but my directory contains this file.

Comment: You need to add a line to your Dockerfile to `COPY` the application code in, so that it's contained in the image.